# Taskscheduler not working properly on windows server

Tags: php, mysql, cron, scheduled-tasks

I was trying to setup a cron to run a php script on my windows server. The script is working fine when accessed manually but it doesn't work via the task schedule.

Here is the problem:

```
// Code to fetch stuff from db
mysqlqueries...
for loop{
// Mail according to fetch content
mail function
}
// Mail a status report at the end to me.
```

I am getting the status report but nothing else, my server is on godaddy and when i chatted with support they said there is "a special syntax for running crons" in php? This is the first time i have heard about such a thing. Can anyone help?

Comment: What command do you use for the "scheduled task"?

Comment: I used the default task scheduler option path/to/phpexe -f path/to/php script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue, nothing needed to be changed in the code. I just had to change from php.exe to php-cgi.exe in the cron call.